# how to Modify lookup column as type able field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I have a lookup column in the SharePoint list, but when we have more number of items in the lookup parent list, it is difficult to select the lookup value. Is there any way to make the lookup column typable to filter the values in the lookup field(like suggestions)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPService to achieve it. You can add your code into NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx as the following image.

A demo for your reference:

```
<script language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "CarBrands", // Source List Name
            sourceColumn: "CarGroup", // Source List Column from where you want to fetch it.
            columnName: "Group", // Destination List Column where you wan to add it.
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Note:It just works for Classic View.